# NPM i is giving "ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/build'"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I tried to install a project. NPM i gave this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWkKE.png)

> npm WARN package.json expresshello@1.0.0 No description npm WARN
> package.json expresshello@1.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN
> package.json expresshello@1.0.0 No README data npm ERR! Darwin 22.2.0
> npm ERR! argv "/Users/vikas.r/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node"
> "/Users/vikas.r/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm" "i" "express" npm
> ERR! node v4.4.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8 npm ERR! path /build npm ERR!
> code EROFS npm ERR! errno -30 npm ERR! syscall mkdir
>
> npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/build' npm ERR!
> rofs This is most likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! rofs
> and is related to the file system being read-only. npm ERR! rofs  npm
> ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems npm
> ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /Users/vikas.r/Code/expresshello/npm-debug.log

I created new folder, did npm init, just tried npm i express. getting same issue

> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir
> npm ERR! path /build
> npm ERR! errno -2
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/build'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent

node -v = 18.15.0
using Mac with M1 chip.

do I have to create build folder anywhere ?

mount = mount
/dev/disk3s1s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk3s6 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk3s2 on /System/Volumes/Preboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk3s4 on /System/Volumes/Update (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /System/Volumes/xarts (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/iSCPreboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s3 on /System/Volumes/Hardware (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk3s5 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, NFS exported, local, journaled, nobrowse, protect)
map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk3s1 on /System/Volumes/Update/mnt1 (apfs, sealed, local, journaled, nobrowse)

pwd = /Users/vikas.r/Code/expresshello

lsblk = zsh: command not found: lsblk

Comment: "npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system" You are on a read only file system, no write is possible, therefore you cant create a folder "/build"

Comment: What is the solution here ? new to Mac :/

Comment: No clue what you did, Lets talk over here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252652/75798953

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of the following commands `pwd`, `lsblk`, `mount`, Do not spam comments.

Comment: Seems like your whole root file system is read only: `/dev/disk3s1s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)` Is this regular Apple Hardware or some kind of Virtualization/Hackintosh?

Comment: regular mac book, M1 chip. I do use docker on it sometimes.

Comment: Docker has nothing to do with this, Im not a apple expert, but "/" to be read only seems normal. `/Users` is your home directory and should be stored somewhere else, has something todo with the automount option, can you create a regular file in your home directory? like "touch foobar.txt"?

Comment: in Users folder I got "touch: foobar.txt: Permission denied"
inside Users/vikas - I was able to create the file.

It was working fine (npm i, npm run dev etc).  I deleted few node versions following an article few days ago from bin and users. That has caused this issue i believe. I reinstalled node, still not resolved.